# Why the lambda expression change LEFT JOIN TO INNER JOIN When i put && condition?

Tags: .net, linq, t-sql, lambda

I  like to generate the left outer join query like below but somehow when i add

> &&  o.sgd.intStoreGroup==intStoreGroup

into the lambda expression it change from ***LEFT JOIN TO INNER JOIN.***

Any mistake in below lamdba expression? and why it change? How so i solve it?

**Model**

```
public partial class Partner_StoreTbl  
 {
        [Key]
        public int intStore { get; set; }
        public int intPartner { get; set; }
        public string varStoreRef { get; set; } 
        public byte tintStatus { get; set; }
 }

 public partial class Partner_StoreGroupDetailTbl 
{
    [Key]
    public int intStoreGroupDetail { get; set; }
    public int intStoreGroup { get; set; } 
    public int intStore { get; set; }

}
```

**LINQ**

```
List<byte> byteValue = new List<byte> { 1 };


var StoreGroupDetail = Partner_StoreTbl.GroupJoin(Partner_StoreGroupDetailTbl, s => s.intStoreRef, sgd => sgd.intStore, (s, sgd) => new { s, sgd })
    .Where(o=>o.s.intPartner==intPartner)
    .SelectMany(o => o.sgd.DefaultIfEmpty(), (s,sgd) => new { s.s,sgd}) 
    .Where(o => byteValue.Contains( o.s.tintStatus ) &&  o.sgd.intStoreGroup==intStoreGroup)
    .Select(o => new MODELS.ViewModels.Partner.StoreGroupDetail
    {
        intStoreRef = o.s.intStoreRef,
        intStoreGroup = o.sgd.intStoreGroup==null?0:o.sgd.intStoreGroup,


    }).ToList();
```

**TSQL I WANT the LINQ generate**

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[intStoreRef] AS [intStoreRef], 
    [Extent2].[intStoreGroup] AS [C1]
FROM  [dbo].[Partner_StoreTbl] AS [Extent1]
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Partner_StoreGroupDetailTbl] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[intStoreRef] = [Extent2].[intStore]  
    AND  [Extent2].[intStoreGroup] = 1
 WHERE ([Extent1].[intPartner] = 1) AND ([Extent1].[tintStatus] IN (cast(1 as tinyint)))
```

**BUT SOMEHOW i Get this**

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[intStoreRef] AS [intStoreRef], 
    [Extent2].[intStoreGroup] AS [C1]
FROM  [dbo].[Partner_StoreTbl] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Partner_StoreGroupDetailTbl] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[intStoreRef] = [Extent2].[intStore]
WHERE ([Extent1].[intPartner] = @1) AND ([Extent1].[tintStatus] IN (cast(1 as tinyint))) AND ([Extent2].[intStoreGroup] = @1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the

```
.GroupJoin(Partner_StoreGroupDetailTbl, s => s.intStoreRef, sgd => sgd.intStore, (s, sgd) => new { s, sgd })
```

you should probably try

```
.GroupJoin(Partner_StoreGroupDetailTbl, s => new { intStore = s.intStoreRef, intStoreGroup = intStoreGroup }, sgd => new { intStore = sgd.intStore, sgd.intStoreGroup }, (s, sgd) => new { s, sgd })
```

and then remove the condition `&&  o.sgd.intStoreGroup==intStoreGroup`

But you'll have to test it with EF/Linq-to-SQL

On the WHY... I don't know exactly why, but I can tell you this:

```
 SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON something WHERE B.Something = C
```

is equivalent to

```
 SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN B ON something WHERE B.Something = C
```

because the `WHERE B.Something = C` strongly implies that `B.Something IS NOT NULL`, and that strongly implies that B has been "found". So if B isn't "found", then the `WHERE` "fails" and the row can't be returned. Like with an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: HI xanatos i got this error when i use your line "Not all path return in lambda.." on this line sgd => { intStore = sgd.intStore, sgd.intStoreGroup }

Comment: @tsohtan I had forgot the new :-) Retry now. And then remember to remove the `&&  o.sgd.intStoreGroup==intStoreGroup`

Comment: Thanks for your response again, it came out what i need now. But could you explain what the purpose of this line s => new { intStore = s.intStoreRef, intStoreGroup = intStoreGroup }, sgd => new { intStore = sgd.intStore, sgd.intStoreGroup }

Comment: and on the 2nd part i not getting why you mean  SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON something WHERE B.Something = C
is equivalent to

 SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN B ON something  WHERE B.Something = C

Comment: @tsohtan on the JOIN you have two conditions, in AND between them. To do it in LINQ you have to create two objects containing the terms of the comparison. `new { x1 = a, x2 = b }`, `new { x1 = c, x2 = d }` will be translated to `a == c && b == d`

Comment: But it's important that the anonymous objects have the same names for the properties!

Comment: thanks for helping, even though im not quite getting on 2nd part, but that was not my question, anyway. and i'm understand how to do the 2 condition in linq now. thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72651/discussion-between-xanatos-and-tsohtan).